# How to export graphs from Spotfire to an existing Word file?

Tags: report, spotfire, export-to-word

I use Spotfire and I would like to export all graphs I need in an existing Word file. Now I save all graph one by one in picture format, then I import in Word  and I insert caption figure always one by one.
Is there a way to automate this procedure?

Answer (score 2):

One way which isn't 100% automated but should lessen your work by quite a bit:

1) In Spotfire, under File\Export\, Export to Microsoft Powerpoint and select "All pages (new page for each visualization)" to get a single slide per visual.

2) Click the Office icon and go to Publish -> Create Handouts in Microsoft Word.

3) Choose "Notes below slides" as the page layout option and hit "OK". Since you have no notes, this will just have blank space.

You should now have a word document with snapshots of all your visuals 1 per page. Feel free to reposition, resize, etc.

Comment: That is the way to do it